# ASP.Net Web API 2 Client

Tags: asp.net-web-api, client

How do you create an ASP.Net Web API client which uses server-side only ASP.Net web forms and requires no client-side script such as JQuery?

Comment: I simply mean that all available examples I can find use client-side script, such as JQuery to generate client views. I'd like an example, or two, of ASP.Net web form applications (where controls have 'runat=server' attributes) and these applications are clients to web API 2 services.

Answer (score 0):

You may use HttpClient class as below.

HttpClient client = new HttpClient("http://localhost:9000/");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(routing url);

Thanks